# Jenkins proxy is invalid when containing integers

Tags: jenkins, proxy

I am unable to set a proxy containing integers in the Jenkins Plugins Proxy.

I have tried to set the proxy and the port.

```
Similar Proxy server: proxy.test-1.com

Similar Proxy port: 8111
```

I have also set the Test URL as `https://www.google.com` and when validating i receive the following Exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Are there any ideas how to deal with it?

Comment: As of today, it's an [open bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-57383) in Jenkins. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved in jenkins version **2.185**